# Has Time in the Universe been found to be Discrete or Continuous?

Tags: spacetime, universe, discrete

I have a question, has the **Universe** been found to come in Discrete Quantum, like Quantum Physics or is it Continuous in Nature?

I was wondering if time was like a **Continuum**, like the fluid in a soft drink for example, and if it "comes into existence" in **Discrete Quantum**, as if someone was taking a "sip" from that drink?

Is there any merit to this kind of **analogy**, or is it all unknown?

I've heard there comes a point when space/time becomes what appears to be **indeterminate** and almost radical departure from the norm of common experience.

Comment: @BenCrowell thanks for the link, should I just leave this on here and avoid deleting it?

Comment: @BenCrowell I updated my question

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9495/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/2451 and links therein.